# TL082 electret preamp and LM386 power amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, microphone, preamp, electret

I have spent the last few days trying to prototype a `TL082` electret mic preamp (based on [this](http://www.circuitdiagram.org/high-quality-low-noise-mic-preamp-using-tl071.html) schematic). I swapped the `TL071` in the linked example with `TL082` (which I understand to be more noise-prone but otherwise similar), made the appropriate changes to the wiring (`VCC` moved to `Pin 8`, signal output moved to `Pin 1`, etc.) and am using `50 Ohm` resistors for the Voltage Divider (as opposed to the `62 Ohm` used in the example schematic) but otherwise my circuit is identical (this was laid out in EAGLE and the PCB cut via CNC, BTW). See below for my schematic.

[image: TL082 preamp by CTA]

As far as I can tell the preamp is sort of working but I am struggling to test and diagnose it. For example: an `LM386` power amp will not amplify the signal from this `TL082` circuit. The `LM386` circuit I use for most things will not amplify the signal from the pre at all (no sound comes out). No idea why, here's a schematic of that circuit below:

[image]

If I plug the `TL082` into a different amplifier, say a [honeytone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000B6DHAS) (which uses the `TDA7052A` IC), I can kind of hear the signal, whereas I get nothing through the `LM386`.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my `TL082` schematic? Should I **not** be using `LM386` to amplify this preamplified signal? Would something else be better? Any suggestions or reccs would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On the LM386 schematic, C4 shouldn't go directly to GND, a small-value series resistor should probably be added - something in the 20 ohm ballpark. And do ensure that those phono jacks are properly mated (audio on tip, ground on ring, shell)...it is easy to cross-wire them.

Comment: @glen_geek good to know! i will try adding 20 and test from there. thx!

Comment: Does it improve if you change R4 and R5 from 50ohm to something closer to 50kohms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Inverting mode amplifier with no Ri.*

Also R3 would normally be connected to ground to discharge C1 and prevent pops when plugging in. As it is it will maximise pops.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks for this feedback. I see that I have omitted `Ri`, great catch. I am a little confused about what value resistor `Ri` should be and whether that is a pull down resistor to ground or would be in series after C1 but before the junction to Pin 2. Could you clarify which you would recommend?

Re `R3`: I will ground that resistor and report back.

Thanks!

Comment: @caseyanderson R3 goes to Vcc to provide a power supply to the electret mic. You'll only be able to ground R3 if the mic has its own (battery) power supply.

Comment: @GrahamNye gotcha, makes sense (and explains the EAGLE behavior I was just fiddling with).

Comment: @Graham: I forgot there was an electret mic involved. Thanks.

Comment: @caseyanderson: Your feedback potentiometer value looks low. Since \$ A = - \frac {R_f}{R_i} \$ (where A is the gain) you could set \$ R_i \$ = 1k and have a maximum gain of 10. 1k is probably to low for the electret to drive well. Try it but I'd expect 10k and 100k for the pot.

Comment: @Transistor, gotcha, trying this now with Ri = 10k and Rf = 100k, thanks so much for your explanation, I understand this now!

Comment: just wanted to follow up about this: adding Ri helped a lot! i get a fair amount of ground hum with how i currently have it but on a basic level i can actually pass the electret signal into an amplifier now. will move on to trying to minimize the hum now. thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an Ri since that preamp is a transimpedance amplifier, which main advantage is lower noise than an inverting amplifier (input is current - output is voltage), see this application note:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu765/tidu765.pdf?ts=1596661260110&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

I would suggest increasing the value of R1 to something closer to 50K, but that will depend on the sensitivity of your microphone, also I would not user a potentiometer there. If you wanna control volume then put a potentiometer at the output of the preamp, but not there.

You could improve a little bit your circuit following that AN.

Probably with a 10K resistor as R1 you do not have enough gain to hear something, but the LM386 circuit looks good to me.